# I am Using Mp Chart android I want yAxis values as showing in a red circle

Tags: android, graph

[image]

```
YAxis leftAxis1 = barChart.getAxisLeft();

   leftAxis1.setDrawLabels(true);

   leftAxis1.setDrawAxisLine(false);

   leftAxis1.setDrawGridLines(true);

    leftAxis1.setEnabled(true);

   leftAxis1.setDrawZeroLine(true);

   //leftAxis1.setTypeface(); // set a different font

   leftAxis1.setTextSize(12f); // set the text size

   leftAxis1.setAxisMinimum(0f); // start at zero

   leftAxis1.setAxisMaximum(100f); // the axis maximum is 100

   leftAxis1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

   leftAxis1.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter());

   leftAxis1.setGranularity(1f); // interval 1

   leftAxis1.setLabelCount(9, true);


    //leftAxis1.setDrawZeroLine(true);

    YAxis rightAxis1 = barChart.getAxisRight();

    rightAxis1.setEnabled(false);
```

}

```
private class MyValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {

    private DecimalFormat mFormat;

    public MyValueFormatter() {
        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.0"); // use one decimal
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        return mFormat.format(value) + " $"; // e.g. append a dollar-sign
   }
}
```

}

I want to have my graph's y-axis values similar to the ones shown in the above image. How would I make it like that? There should be intervals of 10 between for the y-values. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You want each value in Y axis to be +10 ? What does your graph look like now ?

Comment: See my answer, hope this is what you wanted and you will not wast any more time :)

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:

```
mChart.getAxisLeft().setGranularity(10);
```

It will make Y axis values increase by 10 and you will have desired result. Howerever, if you zoomin, the values and graph will be changed (it is normal). If you also want to disable zooming in and out you can disable it :

```
mChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
rightAxis1.setEnabled(false);
```

to

```
rightAxis1.setEnabled(true);
```